# Docker network not accessible on host LAN IP

Tags: routing, docker, linux-networking, centos7

I'm running Centos 7.5 with Docker ce: 18.09.3.
This is my docker daemon config:

```
{
  "bip": "172.18.0.1/24"
}
```

iptables -L -v output:

```
    Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1730K packets, 3080M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    6   489 DOCKER-USER  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    6   489 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    3   272 ACCEPT     all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
    3   217 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2363K packets, 530M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    3   217 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
    6   489 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
    3   217 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   12   978 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

Issue I'm having is that containers are only available inside docker host on 172.18.0.1/24 network. I can't access them from other VMs in same LAN.
Also I can't access containers using localhost on docker host VM.

Any idea what I need to investigate/setup to expose containers ?

Comment: You need to expose ports when you create a container.

Comment: Container is running with -p 3000:3000 option. So containers ports are exposed.

Comment: `iptables -L -v` would be more useful.